# Big an open ball inside small open ball in metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

When i was reading the book "Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis" (A. N. Kolmogorov, S. V. Fomin), I encountered a very interesting (for me) problem.

**Problem**:

> Create a metric space with two open balls $B(x,\rho_1), B(y,\rho_2)$ such that $\rho_1>\rho_2$ and $B(x,\rho_1)\subset B(y,\rho_2)$.

I will post my example, and i would like to know more examples.

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096711

Answer (score 0):

One example: 
metric space $(X,d)$ such that $X(0,1)$ with metrica $d\left( x,y \right) =\begin{cases} 2-\left| x-y \right| \quad ,x\neq y \\ 0\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad ,x=y \end{cases}$

$$d\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 5 }  \right) =2-\frac { 1 }{ 5 } =\frac { 9 }{ 5 } >\frac { 7 }{ 4 } =2-\frac { 1 }{ 4 } =d\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right) \\$$

however $$\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 5 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 5 }  \right) \subset \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 4 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right) $$

Comment: But your intervals aren't balls in your metric?

Comment: is it question?if so,balls are from this metric space

Comment: And at which point and for which radius?

Comment: @gerw,i think it is obvious from the third step)

Comment: No, your intervals aren't balls. In particular, $d(1/2, 1) = 3/2$ and $d(1/2,1/2+1/5) = 9/5 > 3/2$. Hence, each ball around $1/2$ which contains $1/2 + 1/5$ will also contain $1$.

Comment: @gerw,can you explain your argument in detail.I didn't understand really why my intervals aren't balls?) you will be helpful  for me if you post it,and make another metric space which will satisfy above conditions

Comment: my balls are ${ B }_{ 1 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 4 }  \right) ,{ B }_{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 5 }  \right) $

Comment: What are the three values $1, 1/2, 1/4$ resp. $2, 1/2, 1/5$ of your balls?

Comment: $1/2$ is the center of balls,and $1/4$,$1/5$ are theirs radius

Comment: But with your metric, you have $B(1/2, 1/4) = B(1/2,1/5) = \{1/2\}$.