# Find a metric space in which there exist two open balls $B(x,\rho_1),B(y,\rho_2)$ such that $\rho_1>\rho_2$ and $B(x,\rho_1)\subset B(y,\rho_2)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I am reading a famous book by Kolmogorov and Fomin (4th Edition, translated from Russian to Japanese).

There is the following exercise in this book without a solution:

> Find a metric space in which there exist two open balls $B(x,\rho_1),B(y,\rho_2)$ such that $\rho_1>\rho_2$ and $B(x,\rho_1)\subset B(y,\rho_2)$.

My solution is here:

> Let $(X,\rho)$ be a discrete metric space.
> Let $x,y\in X$ be any two elements.
> Let $\rho_1=3$ and $\rho_2=2$.
> Then $B(x,\rho_1)=B(y,\rho_2)=X$.
> So, $B(x,\rho_1)\subset B(y,\rho_2)$.

I think my solution is not interesting at all.
Is there any interesting solution for this exercise? (If not, I think this exercise is not good.)

Comment: Does the subset notation denote a proper subset? If it is, then perhaps the question doesn't have such a trivial answer.

Comment: @YLP In this book $A\subset A$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be the post office metric on $\Bbb R^2$ wrt the origin (so that $d(x,y)=\|x\|_2 + \|y\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm on the  plane for $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$).

Then $B((0,0),1)$ properly contains $B((\frac12,0), \frac43)$, for example.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, Thank you very much for your answer. $d((1,0),(1,0))=1+1=2\ne 0$. So I think $(X,d)$ is not a metric space.

Comment: @tchappyha of course $ \neqy$ is implicitly assumed. I edited.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant answer.

Comment: Let $X=\{0,3,6\}$ with the usual $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$ Then $B(0,5)\subsetneq B(3,4).$